# create .html url on each image using php

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

i want to url on each page like this http://www.damnlol.com/the-new-instgram-facebook-filters-18142.html

using PHP 
now i have uploaded images but display like 
http://mysite.com/veiw_image?img=the-new-instgram-facebook-filters
or 
http://mysite.com/veiw_image?img=10
or 
http://mysite.com/?img=154858

but I want to unique url with .html ext
plz help!

Answer (score 2):

Do some URL rewriting if you use Apache : [Apache2 Guide to URL Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

As said you have to enable `mod_rewrite` on your server, then add a `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view_image/([^/]*)\.html$ /view_image?img=$1 [L]
```

This lets you visit http://mysite.com/view_image/10.html
but also works for your other examples.

---

For anyone searching I thought you originally meant this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpeg$ $1.html
```

Which changes the extension